# How to remove "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error while using steel brick quote calculator plugin

Tags: jsforce

I am getting this error while calling rest api from jsforce on quote calculator plugin .

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://pdc--setup.cs52.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/SBQQ/ShippingCal.
>   **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**.

Origin 'https://pdc--setup--sbqq.cs52.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have created the class for rest api in same organization.

Below is the code for api code in jsforce

```
var PATH = "/services/apexrest/SBQQ/ShippingCal"; 

export function onAfterCalculate(quote, lines, conn) { 
  if (lines.length) { 
    return conn.requestPost(PATH,null) 
    .then(function(res) { 
    console.log(res); 
  }, function(err) { 
       console.log(err); 
     }) 
  } else { 
    return Promise.resolve(); 
  } 
}
```